# Edit column when selected based on content

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I need to find a way to search all columns along these lines:

```
select CASE 
            When substr(column,1,7) = 'Report:' then substr(column,8)
            when substr(column,1,5) = 'Print' then substr(column, 6)
        else column
        end
  from table
```

Any help on syntax and what not would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Providing some data sample and wich are the expected results will help you to get some answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit column when selected based on content

Are you looking for this?

```
UPDATE table
SET 
    column = 
        CASE 
            WHEN substr(column,1,7) = 'Report:' THEN substr(column,8)
            WHEN substr(column,1,5) = 'Print' THEN substr(column, 6)
            ELSE column
        END
WHERE <conditions>
```